# Empty ng-view in IE developer toolbar

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs

I use AngularJS and the ngRoute to show multiple views in my app and the app has to work in IE8+ :(.

When I "inspect element" the ng-view in IE developer toolbar, the ngView contents it's not shown. (because it's dynamically generated?)

Is there a way to overcome this? (a setting in developer toolbar maybe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IE actually has a refresh button that let's you refresh the HTML that has been inserted after developer tools window has been opened. It doesn't refresh the site, but the tools window content.

[image: IE refresh button]

[image source](http://dropshado.ws/post/46430148565/refresh-button-in-ie-developer-tools)

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot, I was looking for this refresh button for a while :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it a requirement to use IE? If that's the case, you may find use of some snapshotting tech like https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html-snapshots

Comment: Do you believe I'm a masochist, to get myself involved with IE for fun? :P Thanks for the tool, I'll give it a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a more advanced browser. Have Have a look at the Batarang plugin for Chrome which extends the Chrome Developer Tools, adding tools for debugging and profiling AngularJS applications.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en

Comment: The app has to work in IE8, otherwise I wouldn't bother :(. My bad for not mentioning it in the question. I'll update the question.